# Scheduling the same activity with different arguments in Amazon SWF

Tags: amazon-swf

I am trying to schedule an activity in Amazon SWF. Initially, I used to loop through a list and schedule the activity for each value of the list. But this would invoke the activities in parallel which I did not want. So, I modified my code to do something like this:

```
Promise<Void> promiseArg = null;
for(Integer i : IntegerList){
   Promise<Void> nextArg = activityClient.activity1(i);
   promiseArg = nextArg;
}
```

Though code is working, I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. Any comments would be helpful.

Comment: It might make more sense to pass the promise to the activity itself (i.e. `promise = activityClient.activity1(i, promise)`).

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of using `promiseArg` if it is unused?

If you want them to be dependent on prev method call, create an `Asynchronous method` and call that with `promise variable`.

```
//Main method of decider.
Promise<Integer> promiseArg = null;
Promise<Integer> nextArg = activityClient.activity1(i, 1);
for(Integer i : IntegerList){
    Promise<Integer> nextArg = fun(nextArg, Promise.asPromise(i));
}


@Asynchronous
public Promise<Integer> fun(Promise<int> nextArg, int i) {
    System.out.println("Testing with current value: " + Integer.toString(nextArg.get()));
    return activityClient.activity1(i, nextArg.get());
}
```

I haven't tested it but it should work.

Apart from this, you can also try passing prev `Promise variable` to activity itself with `@Wait annotation` in the activity declaration.

Something like this,

```
prevArgs = activityClient.activity1(i, prevArg));
```

with Activity like,

```
XYZ activity1(int i,@Wait Promise<int> prevArgs){
   //Please check if int should be used instead of Promise<int>
}
```